# Select by name in SAP with VBA and SAP GUI

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

In my code, when I want to select this row I select it by its position like this:

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "1"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell
```

But I want to select it by the value of first cell (or name of the variant), for example: here it would be "PAL DESCENDUE"

[image]

Does anybody know how can I do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
Set Layout = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell")
RowsL = Layout.RowCount()
For i = 0 To Rows - 1
LayoutVariant = Layout.getCellValue(i, "VARIANT")
If LayoutVariant = "STEFAN3" Then
Layout.currentCellRow = i
Layout.clickCurrentCell
Exit For
End If
Next
```